# ASCII or just use Symbol/Character

Tags: html, ascii, symbols

```
&#169;
```

or just use:

```
©
```

in html.

What is the best use for seo and validation etc?

Comment: How would those chars help SEO? Your contents can drive SEO, not chars like &#169.

Comment: thanks, but why do I see some sites using ascii codes instead of the symbol or character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use ASCII code. Some time on server ASCII symbol is not recognize by server or browser and your ASCII character will get distorted. User will not able to understand that character.
You can get the most of ASCII code from here:http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: As far as I know Search engine only see the ASCII character it will not see whether it is coming by code or just character. As I explain in above answer putting just character is not proper way.